# Python rsync error in reading remote root-level files

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, backup, rsync

I try to setup a cron job to rsync remote files (contains root-level files) into my local server, if I run the command in shell, it works. But if I run this in Python, I got into strange command not found error:

This works if run it in a shell:

```
rsync -ave ssh --rsync-path='sudo rsync' --delete root@192.168.1.100:/tmp/test2 ./test
```

But this Python script doesn't:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import call
....
for src_dir in backup_list:
    call(["rsync", "-ave", "ssh", "--rsync-path='sudo rsync'", "--delete", src_host+src_dir, dst_dir])
```

It fails with:

```
local server:$ backup.py
bash: sudo rsync: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.0]
...
```

Comment: Can you set it to a variable and have it print the output

Comment: how to set to a variable? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I dont think you would need sudo for rsync, and this os.system is more straightforward.

Comment: try removing the sudo from your subprocess as well.  Might work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely a spacing error or something small, the way I debug commands is to make sure to prints out.  OS.system is a great alternative thats easier although subprocess is better. I am not around my computer to test it but you can either set your subprocess like that, or use this example.  This is assuming your on Linux or Mac.

```
import os 

cmd = ('rsync -ave --delete root' +str(src_host) + str(src_directory) + '' + str(dst_dir)) #variable you can call anytime
os.system(cmd) # actually performs the command
print x # how to  test and make sure
```

Answer (score 1):

Quotes around an argument with spaces like you have in `"--rsync-path='sudo rsync'"` are needed when the shell splits up a long string into arguments, to avoid treating `rsync` as a separate argument.  In your `call()`, you're providing the individual arguments, so that splitting of a string into arguments is not performed.  With your code as-is, the quotes end up as part of the argument passed to `rsync`.  Just drop them.  Here's a working example of the list passed to a `call()` for a very similar `rsync` invocation:

`['rsync',
 '-arvz',
 '-delete',
 '-e',
 'ssh',
 '--rsync-path=sudo rsync',
 '192.168.0.17:/remote/directory/',
 '/local/directory/']`

Comment: This should have been an accepted answer in regard to the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue:
This piece of code work for me…
join the command while passing to call or Popen and add `shell=True`.

```
from subprocess import call
for src_dir in backup_list:
    call( " ".join(["rsync", "-ave", "ssh", "--rsync-path='sudo rsync'", "--delete", src_host+src_dir, dst_dir]) , shell=True)
```